# Edamam Meal Planning API returning 401 error with valid app_id

Tags: javascript, edamam-api

I am testing out Edamam's Meal Planning API but am being returned with a 401 error. I have already checked my account application to make sure it is set to the Meal Planning Developer plan so the question of valid id's/key's is ruled out. When testing my id in the documentation's tester it works just fine. This is my code so far:

```
import express from "express"
import axios from "axios" 
import cors from "cors"
import "dotenv/config"

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(cors())

app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const responce = await axios.post(`https://api.edamam.com/api/meal-planner/v1/${process.env.APP_ID}/select`, {
        "size": 2,
        "plan": {
          "accept": {
            "all": [
              {
                "health": [
                  "VEGAN"
                ]
              },
              {
                "cuisine": [
                  "Mediterranean"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      });
      res.send(responce.body)
    }
    catch (ex) {
      res.send(ex)
    }
})

app.listen(PORT,() => {
    console.log(`server is listening to port ${PORT}`)
})
```

If my app_id and app_key are valid I assume that my code must be wrong. Is there something here I'm not seeing? I also tested the documentation's example in postman and was returned with the same error.

Send POST request to edamam's meal planning API endpoint with simple schema data. Expected meal plan responce from edamam. Was returned with 401 "Missing or invalid credentials."

Comment: is that really the correct URL with the "app_id" in the middle of it like that. You also mention an `app_key` - but there seems to be no such thing in your code

Comment: Have you read the [FAQ](https://developer.edamam.com/api/faq)

Comment: Yes the documentation says to pass the app_id in the url rather than as a parameter,  also the FAQ doesn't have any useful information on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You missed your account email in header

```json
const headers = {
  'accept': ' application/json'
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Edamam-Account-User': '[your edamam.com account email]'
}

const responce = await axios.post(url =`https://api.edamam.com/api/meal-planner/v1/${process.env.APP_ID}/select`,
   data = {
        "size": 2,
        "plan": {
          "accept": {
            "all": [
              {
                "health": [
                  "VEGAN"
                ]
              },
              {
                "cuisine": [
                  "Mediterranean"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
   config = {
    headers: headers
  });
```

You can try it from Swagger without any code.

```
https://developer.edamam.com/edamam-docs-meal-planner-api
```

[image]

Comment: The documentation says this parameter isn't required but I tried it out anyways and it returned the same error, I even tried using the account username instead of email and it didn't have a difference. My app_id works on swagger with and without the account parameter.

Comment: I have no license to access it, can you borrow your license, I can try it for you.

Comment: I'm not comfortable giving out my API keys however the licensing is free, [link](https://developer.edamam.com/meal-planner-api)

Comment: I tried it Free license not support Meal Plan (Beta) only demo UI by online, other three Meal Nutrition Analysis API, Recipe Search API, Food Database API seems possible.

Comment: The way you sign up for the API is somewhat confusing. When you create an application, select Recipe Search API. Next, select Plan -> Meal Planner Developer. I think because the meal planner is built upon the recipe search they decided to nest the application location.